# LinkedIn API: Can't fetch posts from Showcase Page

Tags: linkedin-api

We're trying to use the LinkedIn API to fetch posts from a Showcase Page but this doesn't seem to work anymore.

We do the following API call:

```
Method: GET
URL: https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts?q=author&author=urn%3Ali%3AorganizationBrand%3A100585042
Headers: 
- x-restli-protocol-version: 2.0.0
- linkedin-version: 202304
- authorization: ...
```

It returns us the following error:

`{"code":"INVALID_POST_FINDER_AUTHOR_ENTITY_TYPE","message":"Author type is invalid. Only person urn and organization urn are supported for posts finder","status":400}`

Does anyone know how we can fetch posts from Showcase pages?

Thanks!

We tried to do different API calls with different parameters but we received several different errors that indicates that we cannot fetch the posts.